# Codeception REST API seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath не работает

Tags: php, codeception

```
$I = new ApiGuyTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('test suck');

$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->amHttpAuthenticated('username','password');
$I->sendPOST('registration/test/', array('user_email' => 'web@gmail.com','user_password'=>'332222111', 'user_platform'=>'1','user_device'=>'21','user_language'=>'ru'));
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.store');
```

Тест не проходит. Хотя по ссылке все массив выводится нормально

```
{
  "store": {
    "0": {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
      "title": "Sword of Honour",
      "price": 12.99
    },
    "book": {
      "category": "reference",
      "author": "Nigel Rees",
      "title": "Sayings of the Century",
      "price": 8.95
    },
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
Что я делаю не так.
```

Comment: Посмотри что в респонсе `codecept_debug($I->grabResponse());`

Comment: I grab response
 PASSED Больше ничего не выводится

Comment: Step  See response contains json {"status":"OK"}
 Fail  Response JSON does not contain the provided JSON
- array (
  'status' => 'OK',
)
+ NULL
Failed asserting that false is true.

Comment: изменил на простой вывод : {
  "result": "OK"
} Все равно не работает

Comment: по всей видимости возвращает null. Пути и настройки проверил. Все совпадает. И возвращает true $I->seeResponseIsJson()

Comment: включи дебаг, добавив ключ `-d` к команде запуска тестов

Comment: Fail  Response JSON does not contain the provided JSON
- array (
  'result' => 'OK',
)
+ NULL
Failed asserting that false is true.

Comment: Возвращает NULL

Comment: Попробовал на другие api - [ссылка](http://myownapi.juandmegon.com/vehicles ) - тоже самое null

Comment: @I.Prokopenko Пожалуйста, добавьте все комментарии в тело вашего вопроса (для этого используйте ссылку [edit] под телом вопроса).

Comment: Значит с авторизацией проблема, возможно она не нужна?

Comment: Уже без авторизации сделал. Вот такой массив :  {
  "result": "OK",
  "book": {
    "1": {
      "0": {
        "category": {
          "0": "reference",
          "author": "Nigel Rees"
        }
      },
      "category": {
        "0": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees"
      }
    },
    "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees"
  }
}

Comment: `I = new ApiGuyTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Registered User');
$I->sendGET('services/');
$I->grabResponse();
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.data');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в `.htaccess`. Видимо, из-за того, что я включил кеширование сss, js, img. Убрал модуль кеширования из `.htaccess` и все нормально заработало.